# count all occurences of xsl:result-document in a given stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I have an issue with part of my application in which I have some utility classes for xslt transformation functionality. I use SaxonHE as XSLT Transformer implementation.

My helper class has a function: `URL mapFile(URL input, String stylesheetPath)`.

That takes the URL of one XML-File as input and returns a URL for the created XML-File. It handles the initialization and execution of the XSLT transformation.

But a stylesheet could theoretically create multiple XML files with xsl:result-document tags and I would like my utility class to be able to recognize if the given stylesheet will do that and handle it properly.

My idea was to analyse/parse the stylesheet from within my Java code and count all occurences of xsl:result-document.

With the values of the href-attributes, I would also know where the stylesheet creates the output XML files since I want to return a URL that points to their location.

So my changed utility method would be: `List<URL> mapFile(URL input, String stylesheetPath)` and return a number of URLs based on how many files are created by the given stylesheet.

But I have no idea how to do this in Java code and all my google searches concerning counting elements in a xsl stylesheet resulted in explanations how to count XML elements of the input XML from inside the stylesheet, which is not what I want to do.

EDIT:  I ended up not doing any parsing of the stylesheet at all. I just create a folder and if someone writes a stylesheet that doesnt put all result files in that folder then it is their fault if they dont get a URL back for that result document .  A hacky solution but it works for my use-case.

Comment: For Saxon 9.9 and `Xslt30Transformer`, in your Java code you can use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#setResultDocumentHandler-java.util.function.Function- to handle result documents. So such a handler could certainly collect the URIs of result documents but it would be its task as well then to create them. I guess it is possible to delegate that task to existing code, perhaps by subclassing an existing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single-module stylesheet it's very simple: just execute the XPath expression `count(//xsl:result-document)`.

For a stylesheet with multiple modules it gets more complicated because you have to follow `xsl:include` and `xsl:import` references, and more particularly, you have to detect cycles in the include/import graph so you don't go into an infinite loop.

You could export the stylesheet to a SEF file and execute `count(//*:resultDoc)` on the SEF file. Unfortunately that's Saxon-EE which will cost you money, but then writing the code by hand will cost you money too...

But actually you've asked for two different things. First you say you want to know the number of `xsl:result-document` instructions, then you say you want to know how many result documents are created. These aren't the same thing, because you don't know how often each `xsl:result-document` instruction is executed.

I suspect you can solve the problem by registering a result document handler with Saxon and using it to monitor calls on `xsl:result-document` at run-time.

Comment: You are absolutely right. What I wanted was the number of created files but I overlooked the fact that number of result-document tags != number of created files.